# CodeIgniter - escape SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, escaping

I am programatically generating a SQL statement that I then need to execute, however it is failing, I think due to not being escaped properly.

The SQL appears to be generated correctly in that I can cut and paste it from a browser and it executes correctly from the CMD line and PHPMyAdmin. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `1_e6766037c49ccf8cc3f8437c123d6e88` 
(`intId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`twitter_retweet_count` TEXT NULL ,......
```

I then try to execute it using CI with:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

However it fails with:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '
`twitter_retweet_count` TEXT NULL ,.......
```

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong?

Many thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@adidasadida- thanks for your efforts. Your testing made me look further at the generate code and I realised I had an HTML character in there for display purposes (new line). This was the cause of the failure. Many thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the ` character around the column/table names?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 1_e6766037c49ccf8cc3f8437c123d6e88
(intId int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
twitter_retweet_count TEXT NULL ,......
```

Comment: I just tested the code with codeigniter 2.1 and didn't seem to get an error. (I used the sql line with the ` and didn't see a problem) Which version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: @adidasadida- thanks for your efforts. Your testing made me look further at the generate code and I realised I had an HTML character in there for display purposes (new line). This was the cause of the failure.

Many thanks, Ben.